# how to make the json data into jquery code?

Tags: php, jquery

the php json_encode($object) result is

```
[{"price_id":"1","website_id":"0","price_qty":2,"price":"90.0000"},
 {"price_id":"2","website_id":"0","price_qty":5,"price":"80.0000"},
 {"price_id":"3","website_id":"0","price_qty":8,"price":"70.0000"}]
```

someone tell me, `var sorted = arrayWithJsonData.sort(function(a,b){}`

how to use the above php json_encode($object) to arrayWithJsonData.
i used the following way, but it shows TypeError: object.sort is not a function

first: in php i did: `echo '<div style="display:none;" id="object">'.$object.'</div>';` then using in jquery

```
var object=jQuery("#object").text(); // first sort the array var sorted = object.sort(function(a,b){}
```

Comment: I think the error TypeError: object.sort is not a function is from the javascript object arrayWithJsonData, not php

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the object first so javascript(jQuery) can understand it:

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var arrayWithJsonData = $.parseJSON($('#object').text());
```

`$.parseJSON` is a jQuery utitlity for converting a well-formed json string to a json object (jQuery doc: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). In our case, `$('#object').text()` method of the matched element returns the well-formed json string which is the output of the PHP function `json_encode($object)`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your answer a little to help the OP understand why it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayWithJsonData = <?php json_encode($object) ?>;
var sorted = arrayWithJsonData.sort(function(a, b){
    // Sort criteria between a and b
});
```